# Excel - Create list from a range where corresponding value in 0 or Null

Tags: excel

In Excel 2013 how do I bring back a list of items with 0 sales?

eg

[image]

Comment: With a column filter?

Comment: Needs to be formula based in this case, thx.

Comment: Pivot Table will probably be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a Pivot table like this:

[image]

If you really do need a formula this one will offer the best performance, as it is ***NOT*** an array formula and will perform faster and faster on longer list as you get further and further down. Because it only looks at the portion of the list below the last value instead of testing every value in the list for every word everytime.

To start enter

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(0,B1:B10,0))
```

In `D1` to get the first value with a 0. Then in `D2` enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$10,0)+1&":A11"),
 MATCH(0,INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$10,0)+1&":B11"),0)),"")
```

replacing `$A$1:$A$10` with your list of items. And changing the `A11` and `B11` to the row below your last item.

This will result in the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select `E1:E4` range. With selected range enter following formula in formula bar:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A4,SMALL(IF(B1:B4=0,ROW(A1:A4)-ROW($A$1)+1,""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(A1:A4))))),"")
```

and since it's an array formula, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

---

[image]